# Join tables where the condition is not null in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a blog using PHP and MySQL. For a search engine I need a way to restrict the MySQL result so that only posts with images are returned. There is a one to many relationship between a posts and images.

This is the database structure:

`Posts`:
`PostID` (PK),
`userid` (FK),
`Post_timestamp`

Post_timestamp is calculated using the time() function in PHP.

`Images`:
`ImageID` (PK),
`PostID` (FK),
`ImageType`,
`Image`

This is the query I have so far, but there is a syntax error:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT Post.PostID, Images.ImageID, Images.PostID, Post.Post_timestamp
WHERE
    Post.PostID = Images.PostID
ORDER BY
    Post.Post_timestamp DESC
LIMIT
    1,5;
```

I am using limit for pagination; I would like five results per page. The resulting table should display the `Post.PostID` (distinct) if the said `postID` is also found in image table.

Comment: What is the SQL error?

Comment: If you want the top 5 results, try `LIMIT 5` instead.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Post.PostID = Images.PostID ORDER BY Post.Post_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1,5' at line 1

Comment: Same error when I use LIMIT 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot from clause

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT Post.PostID, Image.ImageID, Image.PostID, Post.Post_timestamp
from
    Posts Post,Images Image
WHERE
    Post.PostID = Image.PostID
ORDER BY
    Post.Post_timestamp DESC
LIMIT
    1,5;
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT
    Post.PostID, Image.ImageID, Image.PostID, Post.Post_timestamp
from
    Posts Post,Images Image
WHERE
    Post.PostID = Image.PostID
GROUP BY
    Post.PostID   
ORDER BY
    Post.Post_timestamp DESC
LIMIT
    1,5;
```

use group by

Comment: It executes; but the rows returned are not distinct. <br/>PostID  ImageID  PostID  Post_timestamp
5  5  5  1386526544
5  6  5  1386526544

Comment: @user3103155 try left join

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    P.PostID, I.ImageID, I.PostID, P.Post_timestamp
FROM
    Posts P
    INNER JOIN Images I ON P.PostID = I.PostID
GROUP BY
    P.PostID   
ORDER BY
    P.Post_timestamp DESC
LIMIT
    1,5;
```